# C# - Raise event on PowerStatus change

Tags: c#, event-handling

I've created an application that need to be in a safe state and so I want to follow the power status of the computer in background. If the battery level (if any) is low or critical, I wouldn't allow the user to continue using the application and quit all properly.

First of all, I'm astonished that no such event exists in order to detect the change. You need always to check the PowerStatus manually.

So, I've created a wrapper around it, something like this :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    internal static class BatteryManagement
    {
        //
        internal static event EventHandler<EventArgs> Changed;

        //
        private static bool _started;
        private static System.Threading.Timer _timer;
        private static PowerStatus _previousPowerStatus;

        internal static void Start()
        {
            if (!_started)
            {
                _started = true;
                ManageBatteryLevel();
            }
        }

        internal static void Stop()
        {
            if (_started)
            {
                if(_timer != null)
                {
                    _timer.Dispose();
                    _timer = null;
                }

                _started = false;
            }
        }

        private static void ManageBatteryLevel()
        {
            _previousPowerStatus = new PowerStatus();

            TimeSpan dueTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0); // Start right now
            TimeSpan period = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0); // Run every 1 minute

            // Setting a timer that launch every period the OnBatteryLevelChange method
            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnBatteryLevelChange, null, dueTime, period);
        }

        private static void OnBatteryLevelChange(Object stateInfo)
        {
            PowerStatus powerStatus = new PowerStatus();

            if (!_previousPowerStatus.Equals(powerStatus))
            {
                // Ensure battery level is up to date before raising event
                _previousPowerStatus = powerStatus;

                if (Changed != null)
                {
                    Changed(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But doesn't work because PowerStatus hasn't any public constructor and I can't store the result of the previous status...

How can I manage this ?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually there is, its called the [SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

If the `PowerModeChangedEventArgs` has a `Mode` of `StatusChange`, it means the status of the battery has changed.

```
static void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Mode == Microsoft.Win32.PowerModes.StatusChange)
    {
         // Check what the status is and act accordingly
    }
}
```

This tutorial may also be of use:

http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=30&skatID=277&artID=7643

Comment: That's why I'm looking for ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `SystemInformation.PowerStatus` instead of `new PowerStatus()` if you're trying to obtain the current power status.

Comment: Which gets you a reference, not very useful for storing and comparing in the next tick.

Comment: @Henk: That's what I get for answering the technical part of the question rather than how to solve the actual problem ;) While it looks like @w69rdy has provided the optimal answer, the OP would have to cache the values returned by the `PowerStatus` class rather than the instance itself. I had assumed (incorrectly) that `PowerStatus` was a simple structure rather than an actual class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that will return you all the values of the PowerStatus

```
Type t = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.PowerStatus);            
PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();            
for( int i=0; i<pi.Length; i++ )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property Name {0}", pi[i].Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Property Value {0}", pi[i].GetValue(SystemInformation.PowerStatus, null));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you're rigth, the information at the MSDN is no usefull at all, you will find what you need for your task here:

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/PowerStatus.aspx

I hope it helps!