# Compare two variables every tick

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a simple program to check battery status. I have a timer which ticks every second and I wrote some code, but I think it is not most effective. 
1. I don't know if is the way, how I to check if is a percentage of battery is same as one second before, is right.
2. If I don't check MsgBox then percentage info in Label2 and MsgBox texts are not updated.

```
    class Battery
    {
       public static int BatteryPercentage()
       {
           PowerStatus ps = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;

           int percentage = Convert.ToInt32(ps.BatteryLifePercent * 100);

           return percentage;
       }
    }

    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static int LastPer { get; set; }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int per = Battery.BatteryPercentage();
        label2.Text = per.ToString();
        progressBar1.Value = per;

        if (MyClass.LastPer == 0)
        {
            MyClass.LastPer = per;
        }
        else if (MyClass.LastPer > per && per <= 100)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Battery is almost empty, remain " + per.ToString()  + "!" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not use MessageBox.Show in a timer event (to debug, use Console.WriteLine). In all cases, disable timer at beginning of timer1_Tick and reenable it at the end. Also replace "MyClass.LastPer > per" by "MyClass.LastPer < per".

Comment: A few things that pop up:
1. The 'Battery is almost empty' message will be displayed at almost every timer tick after per<=100. you may not want all those dialog boxes

2. i would consider raising an event on a change in the powermode:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378449/c-sharp-raise-event-on-powerstatus-change. This could be more efficient than spinning up your own timer and polling the status.

Comment: Thanks! @Assaf you right, I forgot to change 100 on 20. I used 100 only for testing.

Comment: Constantly draining battery  by pulling every second is not the best way to measure  status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be more efficient to get rid of your timer and subscribe to the report updated event of the Windows.Devices.Power.Battery class.

Something to the effect of

```
Battery.ReportUpdated += BatteryChargeLevelChanged;

public void BatteryChargeLevelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // show your message if the charge is low
}
```