# Raise event when PC battery percentage changes C#

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.7.2

I am creating a C# desktop application (.NET 4.7.2) where I want the battery percentage to be displayed to the user and updated frequently. I also want the status of charging/not charging displayed. I currently have an event handler to update a property BatteryPercentage, which either displays "P" for plugged in, or a percentage if it is not plugged in. The event SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged gets raised when the PC switches from charging to not charging and vise versa. Here is the event handler:

```
    void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       
        // event doesnt get raised w/ change in battery percent
        PowerStatus power = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;
     
        if (power.PowerLineStatus == System.Windows.Forms.PowerLineStatus.Online)
        {
            BatteryPercentage = "P";     
                
        }
        else if (power.PowerLineStatus == System.Windows.Forms.PowerLineStatus.Offline)
        {
           
            BatteryPercentage = $"{power.BatteryLifePercent * 100} %";
        }      
    }
```

However, I also want to raise an event when the battery percentage changes. So for example, if the battery drops from 95% to 92%, I want an event to be raised so I can update the battery percentage to the user. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378449/c-sharp-raise-event-on-powerstatus-change

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAlam That's pretty much exactly what I'm doing, the event seems to never gets triggered with a decrease in battery life, only when it is plugged in or unplugged from power

Comment: you have to check the current battery percentage by running a thread or timer if the value changes then call the function.  
first time store Current Value in static variable

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAlam I see, I was hoping an event would exist so I wouldn't have to run a timer/check battery percentage but I guess I'll just do that. Thanks!